# Exception occurred: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: content for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy

am getting below error Cloudbees Jenkins job of console output.
error:
Exception occurred: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: content for class: groovy.lang.Binding

## Jenkins file (particular stage):

```
     stage('Solution check') {

      when {
                 expression { params.SOLUTION_NAME_CHECK != 'None' }
            }
        steps {
            script{
            try{
            SOLUTION_NAME = "${params.SOLUTION_NAME_CHECK}"
            bat """
            call pac solution check --path C:\ManagedSolution.zip --outputDirectory C:\\SolutionCheck --geo Asia >> solutioncheck.log
           """
            powershell(returnStdout: true, script: """
                  $content = (Get-Content -Path '${WORKSPACE}\\${DATE_TIMESTAMPED_BN_DIR}\\${SOLUTION_NAME}\\solutioncheck.log.txt' -Tail 3).trim() | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames Critical,High,Medium,Low,Informational
                  $file = $content[1] -replace " ",""
                  $file | Foreach {
                  if(($_ -ilike "*critical=0*") -and ($_ -ilike "*High=0")){
                       echo "solution has no critical and High values"
                     }
                     else {
                       echo "Solution has critical and High values: $content[1]"
                     }
                }
                 """)
                 }
            catch (Exception err) {
                        echo 'Exception occurred: ' + err.toString()
             }
            
                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Please assist on this issue.
thanks lot

- Hemanth

Comment: Use single quotes to define script. In double quotes `$content` is a reference to groovy variable

Comment: @daggett if define single quotes for script, it getting error as
"Get-Content : can not find the path '\solution.log' because it does not exist."

Comment: you are writing to one log file `>> solutioncheck.log` and reading from another one `solutioncheck.log.txt`. also check that `DATE_TIMESTAMPED_BN_DIR` and `SOLUTION_NAME` declared as environment variables: `env.SOLUTION_NAME = ...`. you could use doublequoted string then you have to escape each `$` that is not a reference to groovy variable as: `\$content`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an escape character(\) before `$` for all the non-groovy variables.

```
\$content = (Get-Content -Path '${WORKSPACE}\\${DATE_TIMESTAMPED_BN_DIR}\\${SOLUTION_NAME}\\solutioncheck.log.txt' -Tail 3).trim() | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames Critical,High,Medium,Low,Informational
                  \$file = \$content[1] -replace " ",""
                  \$file | Foreach {
                  if((\$_ -ilike "*critical=0*") -and (\$_ -ilike "*High=0")){
                       echo "solution has no critical and High values"
                     }
                     else {
                       echo "Solution has critical and High values: \$content[1]"
                     }
                }
```